# Suppress installer.OpenProduct(productCode) from popping up C#

Tags: c#, windows, session, popup, installation

I am following [Windows API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a session from an Installer so I can get a session back to [Evaluate if the product has been installed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371656%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). However, after I make the `installer.OpenProduct(productCode)` call, I will get [image: Preparing to install] popping up, how do I get rid of it/suppress the pop up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
installer.UILevel = MsiUILevel.msiUILevelNone;
```

After plenty of research...

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is literally as you say only to find out if the product is installed, then use MsiGetProductInfo(Ex) with the ProductCode and see if you get the ERROR_UNKNOWN_PRODUCT result.

There are plenty of other things you can find out that don't require opening the product.

Otherwise do this or the equivalent:

INSTALLUILEVEL was = MsiSetInternalUI (INSTALLUILEVEL_NONE, NULL);

before your call to suppress UI.

Comment: That would be an alternative, but then I need the session for some other functions, which means a lot of refactoring, so it would be nice there is a solution just suppresses the pop up

Comment: I gave you the solution - MsiSetInternalUI.